# Evaluate multivariate integral (of dependent variables) using monte carlo in R

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximation, monte-carlo, simulation

I would like to evaluate

$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \exp\left(-a\sqrt{(x-b)^2+(y-c)^2}\right)dxdy$

using a Monte Carlo approach ($a$ is a scalar and $b,c$ are in $(0,1)$).

Given that $a,b,c$ are parameters, I think the most sensible thing to do would be to set up a grid of $a,b,c$ and optimize over these values, but I still need to calculate the integral given a fixed $a,b,c$. Can I do something like the following:

```
x<-rnorm(100)
y<-x^2
func_to_int<-function(a,b,c,xval,yval){
  exp(-a*(sqrt((xval-b)^2+(yval-c)^2)))
}

means_vec<-c()
for(j in 1:100){
  set.seed(j)
  u_y<-runif(10000)
  u_x<-runif(10000)
  sim_vec<-c()
  for(i in 1:length(u_x)){
    sim_vec[i]<-func_to_int(a=1,b=.5,c=.5,xval=u_x,yval=u_y)
  }
  means_vec[j]<-mean(sim_vec)
  if(j%%10==0){
    print(j)
  }

}

mean(means_vec)
```

This doesn't really seem correct to me as $x$ and $y$ are not independent. The correct (analytical) solution given $a=b=c=1$ is 0.484999, but what I want to know if this is a reasonable approach given that I know $x$ and $y$ are dependent.

Please note that I only mention R as that is the language I primarily use, but I am more just looking for a general method (if you happen to know a way in R, then great)!

Thanks in advance for your time.

Edit: to

Comment: Have you tried differentiating with respect to a, b, and c?  What do you mean by x and y are vectors?

Comment: I am a little confused. "Monte Carlo" gives numerical answers for specified values of the parameters. You have to simulate for many sets of parameter values to think about optimizing those. Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: @Brian Borchers How would differentiating  w.r.t. a,b,c help?

Comment: Note that I am not familiar with your programing language, so I can't follow what it is doing.  However a straightforward Monte Carlo code would generate two random numbers as x and y and evaluate the integrand for the pair, having fixed a,b,c in advance.  Repeat the process (for the given a,b,c) as many times as you wish and average the results.

Comment: Presumably you will need the derivative of the integral with respect to the parameters a, b, and c in order to use an optimization algorithm on the parameters.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I am sorry I don't quite understand, would you mind elaborating as to how I could code that up (pseudo code is great!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing $a, b, c$, you should be evaluating points at `u_x` and `u_y` rather than `x` and `y`.

Formula for `u_x` and `u_y` are `unif(10000)`.

Edit:

```
func_to_int<-function(a,b,c,xval,yval){
  exp(-a*(sqrt((xval-b)^2+(yval-c)^2)))
}

means_vec<-c()
for(j in 1:5){
  set.seed(j)
  u_y<-runif(10000)
  u_x<-runif(10000)
  sim_vec<-c()
  for(i in 1:length(u_x)){
    sim_vec[i]<-func_to_int(a=1,b=1,c=1,xval=u_x[i],yval=u_y[i])
  }
  means_vec[j]<-mean(sim_vec)
}
print(means_vec)
```

Comment: you forgot to access element of `u_x` and `u_y`.

Comment: Apologies - I had it correct on my local machine.  But my question is more: should I draw from my $x$ and $y$, and if I do so how can I interpret my answer?

Comment: the integration region is a square. why is there  a condition of $y=x^2$? what is the rationale of that code?

Comment: In my real life problem, I have two vectors - $x$ and $y$ which are coordinates of points on a disk.

Comment: you should draw sample uniformly over your domain of interest, currntly, my code gives you `0.4852768 0.4846228 0.4842457 0.4842054 0.4849819`

Comment: Thank you Siong Thye Goh. This resolves my misunderstanding.